# Using jQuery to Modify Google Autosuggest

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write a jQuery function that adds stuff to the dropdown from Google's search bar after I type in a string. If the string is found in an internal map, then I will print the value for the corresponding key in the suggestion dropdown similar to what Google is already doing for weather, math calculations, etc. So far I have this:

```
var map = { 'weather' : 'It's hot!' };
$("lst-xbtn").click(function () {alert( "hey" );});
```

The few things I am struggling with:
1) Instead of click, it should be like an onKey event. How do I look up the proper event?
2) How do I check if a key exists in the map in my function block?
3) How do I add a div element to the dropdown that appears with the value in the map? Also how do I make sure the dropdown has appeared before adding the element.

Comment: 1) I can use events like keyDown, keyUp, keyPress. Got that

Comment: 2) There aren't hashtables in jQuery?
3) I can use insertAfter. Example:  $('<div id="acExtraDiv">The weather is' + map[query] + '</div>').insertAfter("#sugdivhdr");

Comment: You have a quote in your string. That needs to be escaped or your script won't work. `'It\'s hot!'`